# How to print the value message with selected option from given select box in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, label, material-ui

I have a select box in application where user have to select any one option and the moment when user select the option its corrosponding message should be printed along with the selected option for e.g in my code when user select APPLE as an option the corrosponding value of the apple which is "A healthy fruit,better for breakfast" should be printed ,

I tried with this value option but seems not working for me , any clue ?

here is my demo code
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xj3df

The value message is hidden !

Comment: Can you please recheck your codesandbox link ? All I can see is Material UI Select Components.

Comment: sorry i have updated with the correct one !!

Comment: I have not seen any code to print the value ? 
Where you want to print it ?

Comment: right next to the select box i want to print the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the codesandox https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-jvse7

There are couple things I need to change

- Change value from object to string
- Added print message

Selectfield will find the label from the value of MenuItem.